# Kubernetes annotations are not applied

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In my kubernetes deployment file I have a annotation as below

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "24231"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

But when i apply the deployment file it will be replaced with

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: my-app
        version: 4.0.5-164
```

Not sure why my annotations are not coming. It is getting replaced with data from a metadata section as shown below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    appid: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    groupid: DEFAULT
    version: 4.0.5-164
```

K8s version 1.18

Comment: share the content from the YAML file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are showing us different parts of the deployment manifest here, so I think you are confusing the different metadata sections in the same file.

the first section, `.metadata`, is applied to the deployment itself.

the `.spec.template.metadata` section is applied to the pods that are created by the deployment and those annotations will not appear in the top `.metadata` section of the deployment.

**summary**:

if you want to specify labels/annotations for the deployment, use the `.metadata` section.

if you want to specify labels/annotations that are applied to your pod, use the `.spec.template.metadata` section.

if you want to specify labels/annotations for both, specify them in both places.

example:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  MYAPP
  # labels/annotations that are applied to the deployment
  labels:
    app:  MYAPP
    appid: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    groupid: DEFAULT
    version: 4.0.5-164
  annotations:
    whatever: isapplied
spec:
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
      # labels/annotations that are applied to the pods
      labels:
        app:  MYAPP
        appid: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx
        groupid: DEFAULT
        version: 4.0.5-164
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "24231"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

Comment: Finally I got the problem . .spec.template was duplicated so it was taking only one of two

Comment: nice! happy that you got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are putting annotations

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
```

ideally it should in metadata of deployment or pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: annotations-demo
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "https://hub.docker.com/"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

something like

```
metadata:
      name: annotations-demo
      annotations:
        imageregistry: "https://hub.docker.com/"
```

it should be first metadata section instead of `spec.template` one